# Current window size of an xterm window

Tags: cygwin, xterm

I'd like to know my current xterms' window sizes.  I'm using Cygwin.  Is there a command to just print that to the prompt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's an actual xterm, the following should work (tested on a PuTTY session, since I don't have Cygwin installed at the moment):

```
stty -a | sed 's/;/\n/g' | grep rows | awk '{print $2}'
```

In my case, that returned `24`. Similarly,

```
stty -a | sed 's/;/\n/g' | grep columns | awk '{print $2}'
```

returned `80`.

All the commands involved should be standard in Cygwin or any UNIX-like system. I'd be very surprised if they didn't work equally well in a Cygwin console prompt.

Answer (score 1):

Gives you the size in characters:

```
 echo $COLUMNS " " $LINES
```

Whether it works in cygwin? You tell us!

Answer (score 0):

Install the `ncurses` package, then execute

```
tput cols; tput lines
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to *avoid* using a search and replace regular expression and the *sed* command...

**Note:** Run stty -a by itself to determine the position of the *rows* value.

```
stty -a | grep rows | tr -d ';' | awk {'print $5'}
```

In my case (an xterm in Open Solaris running Gnome), this returned 24.

---

If you want to *avoid* using a search and replace regular expression, *sed*, and *awk* ...

```
stty -a | grep rows | tr -d ';' | cut -d ' ' -f 5
```

Again, 24.

---

If you want to *avoid* using a search and replace regular expression, *sed*, grep, and *awk* ...

```
stty -a | head -n 1 | tr -d ';' | cut -d ' ' -f 5
```

Again, 24.

You can find the *width* of your terminal simply by altering one of these commands to point towards the *columns* value of stty -a.

---

If you do not like using stty -a ...

```
resize | grep LINES | tr -d ';' | cut -d = -f 2
```

and

```
resize | grep COLUMNS | tr -d ';' | cut -d = -f 2
```